# Is It Possible to Send a Signal to a Specific pthread ID?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I'm working on a multi-thread scheduling assignment, which involves adding threads to a variety of queues and selecting the appropriate one to execute.

The pthread_cond_signal(&condition) command is completely asynchronous from what I can tell; it's simply thrown into memory and the first thread to find it with the appropriate pthread_cond_wait() will consume it.

However, say I have a vector of thread ids that have been pushed as the thread is created, ie:

```
threadIDVector1[0] = 3061099328
threadIDVector1[1] = 3077884736
...

threadIDVector2[0] = 3294747394
threadIDVector2[1] = 3384567393
...

etc.
```

And I wanted to send a signal *specifically* to the thread with an id that matches the appropriate element of a vector. I.e. the algorithm would be:

```
While (at least one threadVector is non-empty):
    Look at the first element in each vector
    Select the appropriate one to signal by some criteria
    Send a signal to ONLY that thread
    Complete the thread and remove from threadIDVectorX
```

Is there some way to execute the above, or some accepted standard for achieving the same result?

Comment: why not store a condition specific to each thread along with the thread ID? `threadVector1[0].threadID = 3061099328; threadVector1[0].condition = {...};`

Comment: I'm not sure about linux and `pthread`, but I suspect if you were using `condition_variable`, `std::thread` and `atomic<bool>` you could have one `condition_variable` or `bool` per thread, and do it that way. So you'd create your 10 threads, and have a `condition_variable` / `bool` for each

Comment: @Bruno The original way that I generate these threads is by for (i < SOME_DYNAMICALLY_ASSIGNED_NUMBER) {create thread}. As far as I can tell, there's no real way to generate a unique pthread_cond_t for each iteration through the loop in the way you're describing, is there? C++ doesn't support dynamic variable names to my knowledge.

Comment: @MMMMMCK You don't need dynamic variable names. Make a list of threads, and a corresponding list of condition variables. Give thread `i` condition variable `i`.

Comment: @MMMMMCK, I was suggesting defining a struct. Pseudo code: `struct{ thread_id_t threadID; pthread_cond_t condition;}` and assigning it to each threadVectorX items...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to "send" a signal to a specific thread, nor to know which thread among many will be woken by the OS. It is entirely non-deterministic.

You could use the "multiple condition variable" solution as proposed in the comments. But my preferred solution to something like this is a pipe or socket pair. Have the thread doing the waking write something (like a single byte) to the pipe for the corresponding thread to signal it.

This has a lot of benefits in my book. First, it allows bidirectional communication. Your pseudocode loop at the end of your question seems to also want to remove a finished thread from the list, so you need to know when that thread is done. You could have another CV, or you could have the completing thread write a single byte back to the manager object before exiting. Much easier, I feel.

It also allows you to choose between blocking or nonblocking I/O, or to use synchronous multiplexing with `select(2)` or `epoll(2)`. If you were not exiting from the worker threads, but instead wanted to reuse them, the notifying thread would need to know when they're ready for more work. Again, a CV would be fine here, but the file-descriptor approach allows the notifier to wait for *all* of the worker threads in a single `select(2)` call.

The last thing is that I find files simpler. `pthreads` are pretty complicated, and multithreading is already hard enough to get right. I find that files are easier to manage and reason about in a multithreaded context, making it easier to avoid locking or crashes.

Comment: Seconded. It's also well worth looking at ZeroMQ to use instead of a socket or pipe pair. ZeroMQ abstracts away the concept of a socket into something altogether more powerful. The "patterns" can be particularly useful, and go way beyond what you can do with a straight tcp/unix socket or pipe pair. Also a ZeroMQ "socket" can actually be connected via tcp, ipc, or inproc; the latter is interesting because it is implemented purely in-process (shared memory, semaphores), so it's very fast. From a programmer's point of view, tcp, ipc, and inproc all behave the same.